# Timeout for server request made using "Volley" only on Android not iOS

Tags: android, http, web, timeout, android-volley

In one of my application, I am sending request to server using `volley` provided by **Google**.

Problem : Timeout and error object is null on `onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)`

What i have tried so far :

**1) First I got null error object so solved it by using below code :**

```
 @Override
 protected void deliverResponse(String response) {
    super.deliverResponse(response);
 }

 @Override
 public void deliverError(VolleyError error) {
     super.deliverError(error);
     DebugLog.e("deliverResponse", "getNetworkTimeMs : " + error.getNetworkTimeMs());
 }
```

So far I have got that there is `timeout` happening when I got error object `null`.

**2) Now Application is for `Android` and `iOS` and `web` but `timeout` happens only for `Android`.**

Volley log for requests :

```
BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request
```

**Edited Note :**

1. Web services develoed at server end is same for all three instances (Android , Web and iOS).
2. `Timeout` happens when too many users makes requests to the server.
3. **I have set time out to 2 minutes though volley throws timeout in 30 seconds only sometimes**.
4. I have many answers to change server but as it is not possible so any other solution please.

I also like to add that if i can get more information about when timeout can be possible in volley ?

References I have been gone through :

[Optimizing Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887198/optimizing-volley)

[httpclient-often-times-out-using-wifi-is-going-fine-with-3g](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/131222/httpclient-often-times-out-using-wifi-is-going-fine-with-3g)

[long_xmlhttprequest_ajax_requests_timeout_on_android](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/long_xmlhttprequest_ajax_requests_timeout_on_android)

**Edited :**

I have also set retry policy as below:

```
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 48,
                0, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

And also i do not want to retry if connection timeout.

How can i make efficient service call that can solve problem for `timeout`.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the api you are using with volley?. I am using OKHttpStack  which extends HurlStack with volley.

Comment: @Madhukar Hebbar : I have used simple 'StringRequest' class provided by `volley`..!!

Comment: I had similar problems and what I did is I added 0 for DefaultRetryPolicy's timeout value which seems to behave as No/Indefinite timeout.

Comment: You are running into this problem due to too many users requesting at the same time? Seems like an issue from a UX/UI perspective as well. Maybe increasing the timeout will fix the functionality issue, what about the issue of users waiting too long for a response? Users have a short attention span and don't want to stare at a spinner for too long. Maybe increasing the server's performance via Load balancing, or hardware upgrades will be a better solution?

Comment: Have you tried like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21762518/1318946

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i have tried to get solution of this issue for about two months, I did not get any perfect solution. Though I analyze some facts as below :

1. You can upgrade your server's performance
2. I have tried making web-service request using `HttpURLConnection` but still getting same issue over there.

So I think this issue is not specific from volley, but you getting this issue then i would suggest to increase server performance with customizing below `RetryPolicy`:

```
int x=2;// retry count
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_MS * 48,
                    x, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Hope it will help.

Suggestions are always welcome :)

Please comment below if you found more proper solution.

Thanks.!

Comment: Still its not working.. i put the same code as you mention in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you can refer to the following:

Inside [`BasicNetwork.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/idea133/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/BasicNetwork.java), you will find some information such as:

```
...
private static int SLOW_REQUEST_THRESHOLD_MS = 3000;
...
    /**
     * Logs requests that took over SLOW_REQUEST_THRESHOLD_MS to complete.
     */
    private void logSlowRequests(long requestLifetime, Request<?> request,
            byte[] responseContents, StatusLine statusLine) {
        if (DEBUG || requestLifetime > SLOW_REQUEST_THRESHOLD_MS) {
            VolleyLog.d("HTTP response for request=<%s> [lifetime=%d], [size=%s], " +
                    "[rc=%d], [retryCount=%s]", request, requestLifetime,
                    responseContents != null ? responseContents.length : "null",
                    statusLine.getStatusCode(), request.getRetryPolicy().getCurrentRetryCount());
        }
    }
...

// if the request is slow, log it.
long requestLifetime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - requestStart;
logSlowRequests(requestLifetime, request, responseContents, statusLine);
...
```

So, if your project uses Google's volley as a module (not JAR file), you can update `BasicNetwork.java`, increasing `SLOW_REQUEST_THRESHOLD_MS` value, perhaps 10000 (ms) or more, for example.

Another option, according to @neuron's answer at the following question:

> [How to optimize network-queue-take in android Volley? (Volley Google IO 2013)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18110581/how-to-optimize-network-queue-take-in-android-volley-volley-google-io-2013)

I think you can try increase the value of **NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE** by using the following constructor in your app:

```
public RequestQueue(Cache cache, Network network, int threadPoolSize) {
        this(cache, network, threadPoolSize,
                new ExecutorDelivery(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))); }
```

P/S: if you only want the lines `BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request` not displayed anymore without increasing **NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE**, only need to comment (`//`) the line `logSlowRequests...` above (when your app uses Google's volley as a module - not jar file, not `compile mcxiaoke...` in `build.gradle` file)

Hope it helps!

Comment: How can i use this constructor with `Volley.newRequestQueue();` ?

Comment: I think you can try the following `int threadPoolSize = 10;
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 5* 1024 * 1024);
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());        
        RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(cache, network, threadPoolSize);       
        queue.start();`

Comment: @ BNK : Tried..not solved. Again another issue. As i define timeout to be `2 minutes`, volley throws timeout before even 1 minute is not completed. like at 50 seconds. Do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: If you use Google's official volley instead of mcxiaoke's one, you can edit your BasicNetwork.java, increase `SLOW_REQUEST_THRESHOLD_MS`, try 10000 or more. About `another issue` I have no idea :)

Comment: For your timeout issue, try reading https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/volley-users/onA_uS9KAno

Comment: @AndiGeeky: your issue still not solved? How did you use Volley in your project? Google's one or mcxiaoke's one? If Google's and used as module (not jar file), have you tried increasing `SLOW_REQUEST_THRESHOLD_MS` in BasicNetwork.java yet?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class JGet extends Request {
    private final Response.Listener listener;

    public JGet(final String url, List params,
                Response.Listener responseListener) {
        super(Request.Method.GET, NetUtils.getUrlWithParams(url, params), new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                NetUtils.dealVolleyError(volleyError, url);
            }
        });
        this.listener = responseListener;
        this.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20 * 1000, 0, 1.0f));
        LogUtils.e("request-start--->");
        LogUtils.e(url);
        LogUtils.e(params);
        LogUtils.e("request-start--->");
    }
}
```

set timeout time.

Answer (score 0):

Try not using the **require** statement to connect to your database when sending request to a PHP file using volley.
I've noticed a time-out only when I use something like (require "init.php")
But when I directly put my DB connection information in the same file everything seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy( 50000, 5, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT))